# Vladimir Putin: Who is He? (ascriptive or specifying)

Tags: questions

*The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (Pages 270-1) says:

> *Who* cannot be used to question properties, hence can’t be an ascriptive PC. *Who is he?*, for example, can only be specifying. To question properties we need *what...like*, *what*, or *how* (Ch. 10, §7.7).

Is this correct?

In [an article titled "Vladimir Putin: Who is He?"](https://sldinfo.com/2022/03/vladimir-putin-who-is-he/), is the author simply asking the identity of Vladimir Putin? Or is the title somehow ungrammatical because it's questioning the properties of Vladimir Putin?

### EDIT

Here's what CGEL means by the adjectives "ascriptive" and "specifying". I hope this will make the question easier to answer and discuss:

> ii *The victim was his sister.* [ambiguous: ascriptive or specifying]
>
> The specifying reading identifies who the victim was; the ascriptive reading doesn’t do this but merely says that she was related to him as sister. In the ascriptive use he may have several sisters, while the specifying one implicates that he has only one – and in the negative *The victim was not his sister* the ascriptive reading is perfectly consistent with his not having a sister, while the specifying one strongly implicates that he does.

Comment: Ordinarily, _who_ is only used to ask a person's identity - 'Who is that lady?'. However, in spite of what the Cambridge Grammar says, it is sometimes used to mean 'What kind of person is X?' For example, in the Shakespeare song [Who is Silvia?](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/50684/song-who-is-silvia-what-is-she) the singer obviously knows who Silvia is, and is asking for more information about her.

Comment: The first line of the song is "Who is Silvia? **what** is she”. CGEL is right: "who" questions identity and thus cannot be an ascriptive NP.

Comment: @BillJ - Are you then saying that it's incorrect to use _Who is V. Putin?_ to imply 'What sort of person is he?'?

Comment: @BillJ In "**Who is Silvia?** *{what is she, / That all our swains commend her?}* / **Holy, fair, and wise is she**; / The heaven such grace did lend her," -- "*what is she...*" is in parentheses and rhetorical. The answer to the initial, and only real, question is "**Holy, fair, and wise is she**. Obviously the writer knows Silvia as he is able to give a description, and thus is not asking for her identity. "Who is X" can be used  to question properties, where the identity of the person is dependent upon those properties, e.g. "Who is X - saint or sinner, man or monster?"

Comment: Who am I to comment on this?

Comment: @Greybeard Nothing you say has any relevance to the elementary (and useful) 'rule' that "who" is not prototypically used for questioning properties.

Comment: "Who is [*this man named*] Putin?" the sentence is grammatical and anyone reading would immediately understand its meaning. We understand that Putin is a secretive person, so pundits may speculate about his motivations and what his next tactical move will be but nobody really knows.

Comment: At last. 'Who cannot be used to question properties' has been corrected to '[there exists] the elementary (and useful) 'rule' that "who" is not prototypically used for questioning properties.' Claims for infallibility can be henceforth judged more appropriately.

Comment: @KateBunting This answer seems to assume the two questions are distinct. But I don't see how we can separate the concept of identity from that of *further information*. An object's identity would seem to be constituted just of all the information (or properties) it may be said to have or be about. If a person sees my photo and *identifies* me, very well. And if they see my photo and learn further my name, my height, my weight, etc, then surely this only serves to enrich their *identification* of me. The concepts of identity and of further information are of a piece.

Comment: @PoundHash I like your approach. I've edited the question to include how CGEL says you can distinguish between "ascriptive" and "specifying". I'd like to know what you think of the distinction.

Answer (score 2):

I'm choosing to use standard English definitions rather than in-house stipulative definitions, as I don't believe that answers should be tailored to specific analyses when they have purloined terms with an existing meaning.

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ascribe) gives the definition

> - **ascribe**: [transitive verb]
>
> to refer to a supposed cause, source, or author: to say or think that
> (something) is caused by, comes from, *or is associated with a
> particular person or thing*

[and](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ascriptive)

> - **ascriptive** [adjective]:
>
> relating to, marked by, or *involving ascription*

[emphasis mine]

So in the broadest sense (and possibly the one that makes sense here out of these alternatives) [merely] 'saying something about a person, object etc'. Adding details.

We can all agree that 'specifying' here means 'serving to uniquely identify an individual'. If we were trying to distinguish 'intrinsic/essential' and 'peripheral', I'd say this soon becomes one for the psycholinguists or even theologists and as such off-topic here.

Obviously there will be an overlap. With regard to adjectives, Warren, in 'Classifying Adjectives' (1984), suggested that premodifying adjectives may *classify*, *identify*, or *describe* the head noun, but that care needs to be taken to correctly distinguish these functions in individual examples.

......................

Yes, 'who' is also commonly used to ask about attributes as well as identity, of people who are well known (at least on the surface).

Of the freely available major dictionaries, only [R H K Webster's](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/who) seems to pick up on this usage of the interrogative pronoun, asking about attributes (sense {2} below) rather than for identification as a particular element of a set (sense {1}):

> **who** [pronoun]
>
> - 1. what person or persons?: Who is he? [asking for identification]
> - 2. (of a person) of what character or importance: *Who does she think she is?*

Some examples:

> - Just Who is Boris Johnson? ... He's been mayor of London and a prominent Leave campaigner, a newspaper columnist and foreign
>   secretary, but what else do you need to know about the Conservative
>   leader?

[[BBC News July 2019 – The News Explained](https://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/p07frr6t)].

[asking for a potted biography, warts and all, rather than just the answer 'the current {from July 24 2019} / next {earlier in the year} Prime Minister of the UK')

> - Who is Donald Trump?
>
> The incumbent President of the United States, Donald J Trump was
> elected to office in 2016, beating Democratic nominee Hillary Clinton.
> This time around, he is fighting to stay in office till 2024 and is up
> against former Vice President Joe Biden.
>
> Trump is one of the oldest serving Presidents, having taken the oath
> when he was 70 years old. A businessman and real estate mogul, Trump
> is the only President to not have any military or government service
> prior to taking office.
>
> Previously a Democrat, he registered as Republican in 2009.

[[The Economic Times; updated 2020](https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/news/international/world-news/who-is-donald-trump/articleshow/78315758.cms?from=mdr)]

> - Just who is Joe Biden?
>
> Americans have rejected the presidency of Donald Trump and elected the
> ultimate Washington insider. Joe Biden defined this election as "the
> battle for the soul of the nation” and it is a battle he has won.
>
> Michael Vincent looks at America's next Commander-in-Chief.

[[ABC; Nov 2020](https://www.abc.net.au/7.30/just-who-is-joe-biden/12865474)]

> - Who, exactly, is Julia Fox? 5 things to know about the Uncut Gems star ...
>
> One thing we can be sure of is that Carmela Soprano would approve of
> this Italian-food-based courtship—but what else do we know about Fox,
> the Uncut Gems star and all-around It girl who looks like Debi Mazar
> crossed with Jessica Rabbit, talks like a Long Island pageant queen
> who’s spent more than a little time hanging out with the skaters in
> Dimes Square (to be clear, that’s a huge compliment), and seems to
> have captured West’s heart? Read on to learn more about who she is and
> what makes her tick.

The heading is interpretable as a reformulating (synonymic) attributive.

[[Vogue; Jan 2022](https://www.vogue.in/fashion/content/who-exactly-is-julia-fox-5-things-to-know-about-the-uncut-gems-star)]

And an article paralleling that OP cites:

> - Vladimir Putin: Who is the Russian President, and what does he want?
>
> Vladimir Putin is the President of Russia, and has been the country's
> leader for more than 22 years.
>
> He has been in the news a lot recently because of his decision to
> invade the country of Ukraine.
>
> President Putin has led Russia for a long time, but he's quite a
> controversial figure and opinions about him are very divided – both in
> Russia and around the world.
>
> Some see him as a strong, charismatic leader who has worked hard to
> earn Russia a place alongside some of the most powerful countries in
> the world. Opinion polls in Russia often say how popular he is among
> his people.
>
> But critics think he leads by force, that he has taken away many
> people's freedom, and disagree with how he runs Russia and deals with
> world affairs.
>
> So, who is this leader? And why do so many people have such different
> opinions about him?
>
> Vladimir Putin grew up in an area which is now St Petersburg. He
> didn't come from a rich background and his childhood was quite tough.
>
> It is reported that he used to get into fights when he was younger
> with boys who were bigger and stronger than him, which drove him to
> take up judo and earn a black belt.
>
> According to the Russian government, even before he finished high
> school, he wanted to work in intelligence, and he later went on to
> become a spy.
>
> His political career began when he and his family moved to Moscow in
> 1996, and he quickly became an important political figure....

[BBC Newsround; Feb 2022](https://www.bbc.co.uk/newsround/60521909)]

In reading out such introductory questions, the *is* (or *was*) will typically be stressed:

Who *was* Sir Winston Leonard Spencer-Churchill?

Comment: Those are not denoting properties of those concerned. "Mayor of London and a prominent Leave campaigner", are specifying.

Comment: 'Joe Biden defined this election as "the battle for the soul of the nation” ' is far more descriptive than specifying. But one can often justify set opinions; the 'attribute vs identifying' debate soon becomes open to opinion.

Comment: The chief problem with CGEL is that its acolytes tend to accept the content as "rules" and become apologists for CGEL. It should not be forgotten that "There are no rules in English, only guidance. Some guidance looks like a rule; it probably isn't."

Comment: In this particular question, the two choices are terms defined elsewhere in CGEL, and the distinction between them is not specified. If you substituted _green_ for _ascriptive_ and _red_ for _specifying_, the discussion would make as much sense.

Comment: @Greybeard  Who said anything about CGEL? FYI, there is no 'chief' problem with CGEL, as you put it. In fact it's the opposite of what you imply, which you'd know if you ever bothered to study it. CGEL is the most rigorously researched and respected comprehensive grammar ever published.  It's a useful guide for most, though not of course for those whose preferred grammar is based on fuzzy or out-of-date 'rules' that are of no use to anyone.

Comment: @BillJ *Who said anything about CGEL?* I refer you to the OP's question upon which you commented.

Comment: I think it's also significant that these examples are headlines, which often do not follow standard grammar. Also, these are rhetorical questions.

Comment: @Barmar Are you sure they're rhetorical questions? AFAIK, rhetorical questions are not asked to elicit information. But these questions do elicit information. Aren't you talking about "hypophora"? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypophora

Comment: @Greybeard I was referring to Edwin's particular answer. Comments about CGEL would be better made to the OP. FYI, there are 'rules': they form something called 'Standard English'.

Comment: @JK2 Yes, although I think hypophora is a kind of rhetorical question. The questioner knows the answer, and is not expecting someone to answer it. But true rhetorical questions make a statement in the form of a question ("Who the hell does he think he is?")

Comment: I've edited the question.